# Make account stay connected with ZNC

Tags: irc

Is there a way to make my irc account stay connected when I've disconnected from ZNC?

The buffer feature in ZNC works perfectly, however I would like people to be able to query me, while my client is not runnning.

I'm running ZNC version 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Channels can be detached in two ways:

```
/detach #chan
/quote detach #chan
```

A simple join will reattach you:

```
/join #chan
```

Source: http://wiki.znc.in/Detaching

Comment: Is there a way of automatically detaching from all channels when closing my IRC client and rejoining when connecting again?